# ASP.NET MVC - How Can I Calculate the Total Value With Sum and Count in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, count, sum

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. There are 2 tables in my database named "tbl_Project" and "tbl_Note". Each project can have one or more notes, so I keep/save the "ProjectID" variable in the "tbl_Note".

What I want to do: On the page where the project list is located, I want to show the total number of notes for each project. I tried a few things but I've fail.

This is my projects list page:

```
@if(Model.Any())
{
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Total Note</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Contract Start Date</th>
                <th>Contract End Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Total number of notes will come here -->
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Project", new { ID = item.ID })" data-tooltip="@(item.Information != null? item.Information:"")">@item.ProjectName</a></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @item.ContractStartDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.ContractEndDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <p>Project is not available!</p>
}
```

I've try something like this but it's not working:

```
@if(item.tbl_Note != null)
{
    if(item.tbl_Note.ProjectID == Model.ProjectID) 
    {
        @Model.Sum(b => b.tbl_Note.ProjectID.Count)
    }
}
```

This line gives an error: item.tbl_Note.ProjectID and the error is: 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'ProjectID and no extension method 'ProjectID' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found.

How can I calculate the total number of notes? And if there is any other code block you want to insert, please tell me.

Comment: hi can you try @item.tbl_Note.count();

Comment: this should solve your problem if you have foreign key, but i advice to have null check also once.

Comment: Thanks sir. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error, `item.tbl_Note` is of type `ICollection<T>` and you are looking for a `ProjectID` property in it.

Change it to:

```
@if(item.tbl_Note != null)
{
    @item.tbl_Note.Count
}
```